# cannot execute binary file on 64bit system

Tags: bash, binaryfiles, chmod

I don't understand why i'm getting this error... Is this a path issue??

I have a 64bit system

```
[XXXXXXXX ~]$ uname -m
x86_64

[XXXXXXXX ~]$ file AAAAAAA.bin
AAAAAAA.bin: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped

[xxxxxxxxx ~]$ ls -lha  ./AAAAAAA.bin
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user.name user.name 161M Sep 27 13:07 ./AAAAAAA.bin

[xxxxxxxxx ~]$ sudo sh ./AAAAAAA.bin: cannot execute binary file
```

Why can't I execute the file??? Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Questions about **using** UNIX systems are not on-topic here -- consider instead [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). Only questions about **developing software** are within scope on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't execute this file with `sh` because this is not a shell script.

Execute it directly instead:

```
./AAAAAAA.bin
```